# How can I close my application on back pressed

Tags: android

I want to close application  when I press device's back button.I am using this code..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
       this.finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does it :

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped ;)

Comment: i try like this but i have  error  when app is startig  @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 }
 public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     finish();
 }

Comment: @user3345767 You can only one use the method above "onPause" and this will do the work , no need to use onBackPressed etc..

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed()` in your `Activity` where you want application to Quit when the device back button clicked

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Comment: May be because the above code kills entire app, The word `close` is different from `kill`...

Comment: In the above scenario.I hope this answer would satisfy the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you marked as correct will stop the app every onPause of this activity, which is not an event of the back button cick, the right answer is :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```